# Check if HTTPS Web Service is available with HttpWebRequest and X509 SSL certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpwebrequest

I need to implement a method that checks if a web service is available.
The main problem is that the URL is HTTPS and **requires a certificate**.
So I need to get the certificate from the machine and then create a `HttpWebRequest` to get a `HttpWebResponse`.

With my actual implementation I can retrieve the certificate but when I call `request.GetResponse()` method it throws this Exception:

> [System.Net.WebException] = {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"}

InnerException:

> [System.IO.IOException] = {"Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from
>   the transport stream"}

I read many possible solutions around but none seems to work for me.
I'm on **.NET 3.5**.

**This is my code**

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertificateThumbprint, false);

    if (certificates.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("No corresponding certificate found.");

    X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];

    // Not compiling on .NET 3.5
    // Error: cannot apply '+=' operator to 
    //'System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback' 
    //and 'anonymous method'
    //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    //    delegate(
    //        object sender,
    //        X509Certificate certificate,
    //        X509Chain chain,
    //        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    //    {
    //        return true;
    //    };

    // Not compiling on .NET 3.5
    // Error: cannot apply '+=' operator to 'System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback' and 'lambda expression'
    // ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    // Not working
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    // Not working
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlWSInvioComunicazioni);
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    // throws Exception...
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    webResponse.Close();

    response.ResultCode = ResultCode.Success;
    response.ResultMessage = "Service available.";
}
```

**Update 2017/05/10**

Since I'm on .NET 3.5 that didn't support TLS 1.2, I'm using a patch from Microsoft (see [KB3154519](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/kb/3154519)) that makes possible to use TLS 1.2 by using `SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions` and `SslProtocolsExtensions` extension classes.

I already used that method with some other web services since January 2017 (when Microsoft released the patch) and it works without any problem.

I think that the problem that I have now:

> [System.Net.WebException] = {"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}

has to do with something in my PC.

**Update 2017/05/12**

I finally found that the problem was **related to IIS**. The Application Pool of the web application on my PC was running with Identity set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. When set to `LocalSystem` or my current user (administrator), it worked.

So I think that something with the access to certificates is not correct while the Application Pool runs as ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Answer (score 1):

scan the URL to see what SSL providers the server is using. You can do that here -> https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

[protocols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OAUS.png)

some server have the ssl3 disabled for security reasons. So you have to use this setting instead:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

or use Tls 1.2 if is available on the client.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

**Update**
Check if this code is working for you

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
httpRequest.Method = "GET";
httpRequest.ContentType = "text/html";

httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
httpRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 30;

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
var responseStream = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());

var strResponse = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

httpResponse.Close();
responseStream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Great site! ;-) It seems that only TLS 1.2 is used ([link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=testservizi.fatturapa.it)). But on my code I've only `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` and `SecurityProtocolType.Tls` and not `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. So what can I do...?

Comment: The SLL providers are installed on OS so you have to check what providers are installed on you system. Use [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto)  it will tell you what providers you can use. If Tls 1.2 is not installed you have to change the OS. Windows Server 2008 R2 is the first windows to have tls 1.2 support.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 latest build. But I'm using VS 2012 and .NET 3.5.

Comment: Try this one ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

Comment: No way... It throws another Exception: `[System.Net.WebException] = {"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}`.

Comment: use [whireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/#download) to debug the TCP connection.

Comment: After the connection debug with _Wireshark_ I found that the problem is that the server respond with a Encryption Alert and handshake failure. But in my PC everything seems to be in right place: certificate (correctly added to the request), ciphers (same order as server) and TLS 1.2. I finally made a test with exactly the same application on our test machine and there it works! So it's a problem of configuration on my PC, but I can't understand what...

Comment: Your code works. So my problem must be with the certificate.

Comment: you can try to remove the ClientCertificates entirely and see if it works. Or try to remove the certificate and add it again.